# JSON list of files in Google Drive

Tags: json, google-drive-api

I have a code snippet that takes a list of pictures in PICASA public album and constructs a list used in slider. The simplified code looks like this:

```
var usrID = "555555555555555555555";
var albID = "5555555555555555555";
$.getJSON(
"https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/"+usrID+"/albumid/"+albID+"?alt=json&kind=photo&hl=en_US&callback=?",
function(data) {         
  var picAlbumLst = '<ul id="slider">';
  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, element) {
    var picUrl = element["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].url;
    picAlbumLst += ( 
    '<li style="text-align:center">'+
    '  <img src="'+picUrl+'"/>'+
    '</li>'
    );
  });
  picAlbumLst += "</ul>\n";
  ...
});
```

I am thinking about moving my pictures from Picasa to Google Drive. Is there a way to make a request similar to my old PICASA one in order to get the URLs from Google Drive (anonymous user)? The closer the syntax, the easier the port would be (I have it all over the place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many times before, I posted a question because I was too lazy to work on it harder. But I managed to resolve it in the end. So, here is the Google Drive solution:

1/ perform all the "OAuth 2.0" dances in order to gain access to the folder [IMAGE_FOLDER_ID]. The app has to be authenticated/authorized even if the folder is public.

2/ don't forget to load the API for the Google Drive service

> gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequestCB)

... and here's the loop to retrieve the file URLs

```
function makeRequestCB() {
  gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'q': '"[IMAGE_FOLDER_ID]" in parents',
    'fields' : 'items/id'      
  }).execute(function(resp) {
    var picAlbumLst = '<ul id="slider">';
    for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
      var id = resp.items[i].id;
      picAlbumLst += ('<li><img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id='+id+'"/></li>');
    }
    picAlbumLst += "</ul>\n";
  });
}
```

Comment: so there's no way to do it without authenticating with oAuth.. get data from public folder without oAuth? from the client.. with just the API key and it doesn't work